# Docker Version is not showing on Mac Terminal

Tags: docker

When I type `docker --version` on terminal, it does not show the docker version and says command unknown. However I have installed docker on my machine

Comment: Whilst many Docker-related question are deemed on-topic here, I would argue that since this is simply about the installation, this question would be better posted elsewhere.

Comment: another command work ? as 'docker system'

Comment: does `docker` work?

Comment: I think your docker bin not in your system path. Can you try to execute `echo $PATH` or `which docker`?

Comment: Yes @xwlee I can see the bin location on terminal when I write `which docker` on terminal